# RESTful API in both XML and JSON - best approach to request validation?

Tags: java, xml, json, api, rest

Does anyone have experience developing and maintaining APIs that support both XML and JSON? I'm looking for some clues on how to implement request validation for both XML and JSON.

Background:
We have a java based application exposing RESTful API. It accepts xml requests which get validated against xml schema and then unmarshaled to DTO objects using JAXB.
All works nicely but recently we've got a requirement to support JSON as well.

Now, we could continue validating xml against xml schema and use json-schema for json. The json-schema spec (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-04) is still a draft (and already expired one!) but has already some pretty mature looking implementation in java: https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator.
The obvious drawback is that we'd forced to maintain two schemas (xsd and json-schema) which is a bit of a pain.

The other option would be to first unmarshall/deserialise request to dto and use something like hibernate validator on annotated dto classes. The advantage would be that we'd have same validation rules for both xml and json in one place. However the validation would be less robust/reliable because we'd create objects before checking the request.

At the moment I'm inclined to choose the option 1 and sacrifice maintainability for robustness.

Are there any other possible solutions?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a tool like Jackson, which can serialize to both formats?

Comment: The problem is not about serialisation. It's already been implemented and works pretty well. I actually do use jackson for json serialisation (it supports JAXB annotations pretty well). 
However, I am looking for some sensible validation approach.

Comment: Ah, I see. Read too fast. The question is when to do validation, before or after unmarshalling. I guess I don't see the downside to #2. How is robustness/reliability affected by validating the DTO instead of the JSON/XML? You're creating one cheap object and then either throwing it out right away or using it for the rest of the request. I think you run a significant risk of the schema getting out of synch. And I don't think there are any other solutions - you have to validate, and it can be before or after unmarshaling.

Comment: I guess there is always a risk about creating objects containing non-validated user provided input. For example it might make the app more vulnerable to DoS attacks. to E.g. someone would start creating requests containing huge values that would either cause overflow or memory leak.

Comment: Well, sure, but unless you're deserializing into a stream and validating as it streams out, you're still putting those huge values into memory.